# Command or tool to display list of connections to a Windows file share

Tags: windows, networking, filesystems, biztalk, biztalk-2009

Is there a Windows command or tool that can tell me what users or computers are connected to a Windows fileshare?

Here's why I'm looking for this:

I've run into issues in the past where our deployment team has deployed BizTalk applications to one of our environments using the wrong bindings, leaving us with two receive locations pointing to the same file share (i.e. both dev and test servers point to dev receive location uri).  When this occurs, the two environments in question tend to take turns processing the files received (meaning if I am attempting to debug something in one environment and the other environment has picked the file up, it looks as if my test file has disappeared into thin air).  We have several different environments, plus individual developer machines, and I'd rather not have to check each individually to find the culprit.  I'm looking for a quick way to detect what locations are connected to the share once I notice my test files vanishing.

If I can determine the connections that are invalid, I can go directly to the person responsible for that environment and avoid the time it takes to randomly ask around.  Or if the connections appear to be correct, I can go directly to troubleshooting where in the process the message gets lost.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can either type `net session` on the command line, or go to Computer Management -> System Tools->Shared Folders->Sessions to see who has open session on a share.